# I'm trying to split up my illustrator artboard into even sections using the rectangular grid tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have my artboard set up to represent a playing field which is measuring at 140 meters by 81m. I currently have my artboard set at 140cm by 81cm. Is there a way I can use the rectangular grid tool in Adobe Illustrator to split my artboard into 1662 even sections? Rectangles or squares, as long as they are even sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use another tool:

1. Draw your rectangle
2. Go to menu Object → Path → Split Into Grid
3. Check flag Preview and tune the options
   [image]